# Test if all higher bits are set

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Given a uint16 with one and only one bit set (n), I want to test if bit_rank has all the more significant bits set. I'm currently using for loop but I'm sure there's a clever bit fiddle with just a couple operators. This code uses a compiler where bit operations result in a 32-bit int.

```
uint16_t b; // loop variable
uint16_t n; // one and only one bit set
uint16_t bit_rank; // contains n and possibly higher/lower bits than n
for (b = n << 1; b < 0x10000; b <<= 1)
    if (b & bit_rank)
        continue;
    else
        break;
if (b == 0x10000)
    printf("all bits from n to 0x8000 are set");
```

Comment: Does it work? The last comparison `(b == 0x10000)` seems a bit suspicious to me... (pun not intended)

Comment: Not sure to fully understand what you want, but isn't `if (n & bit_rank == n)` what you need?

Comment: Can you add data sample with expected output?

Comment: Doing that will not test if more significant bits than n in bit rank is set, it will only test if the nth bit in bit rank is set

Comment: if b is uint16_t then `b < 0x10000` will **always** be true and `b == 0x10000` is always false

Comment: @CiaPan operations performed on b are performed using int (not uint16_t), therefore the code works.

Comment: Well, the code 'works', but... What is the maximum value that can appear in `uint16_t b`...? Specifically: what is the most significant bit that can possibly be set in `b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simple solution is

```
((uint16_t) ~bit_rank) < n
```

which works since for something to be less than `n`, the bit of `n` plus all higher bits need to be zero, meaning `bit_rank` (which by assumption does contain the bit of `n`) has all bits higher than that of `n` set.

Comment: Looks like your answer and the comment left by @4386427 are equally good and clever. I'm marking your answer as correct.

Comment: @bsalita: if this answer is correct, you have misstated the requirement. Consider `n == 1` and `bit_rank == 0xfffe`. `bit_rank` has all bits higher than `n` set, but `(uint16_t)~bit_rank` is 1, which is not `< n`. So perhaps both your requirement statement and the code in your question are incorrect, and you meant "`bit_rank` has **n and** all higher-order bits set." If so, you should correct the question (and I'll delete my answer, which is for the specification in the actual question).

Comment: The comment for `bit_rank` in the question states "contains n and possibly higher/lower bits than n" which I interpreted to mean that the bit set in `n` is known to be also set in `bit_rank`, as you suggest.

Comment: @FalkHüffner Exactly. One has to read the question fully to form the correct answer. This is a frequent problem on stackoverflow.

Comment: @FalkHüffner: but that's not what the code actually does, since the loop starts with `b = n << 1`. I based my reading on the text in the question plus the behaviour of the example code, which are consistent. One could equally say that a frequent problem with SO is inconsistently phrased questions.

Answer (score 5):

If unsigned value b has exactly one bit set, then adding b to some unsigned value x of the same type, and casting or coercing the result to that type (if less than "int") will yield a value at least equal to b, if b or any higher bits were clear, and less than b if b and all higher bits were set.

Note that if the type of b and x is smaller than "unsigned", adding b to x in the "all upper bits set" case will yield a result which is too large to fit in the type of b and x.  Casting or coercing the result to the smaller type would yield a value less than b, but otherwise the result would be larger.

Comment: Much better than my answer. All OP needs are: `uint16_t c = bit_rank + n; if (c < n) printf("bit_rank has bit N and all the more significant bits set\n");`

Comment: @4386427 Nope. Disproved if any single bit greater than n is set.

Comment: @4386427 Previously I wrote that your answer was wrong but now I realize that your solution uses overflow and seems quite correct. Thank you. Good answer.

Comment: @BSalita Seems there is a little confusion here. This answer is **written by supercat**. It's not written by me. I did post an answer but deleted it again because this answer is better than mine. BTW: If this answer helped you, consider aaccepting it.

Comment: @4386427 I give credit to code over words. His answer lacks code. That's why you left code in your comment. I thank you both but I prefer the marked answer because it's equally good code but more robust answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try right shifting (>>) your bit rank by whatever bit position in n is set. Then you only have the more significant bits than that position in bit rank. Then reverse (~) the bits of the right shifted bit rank, and test the value, if it is 0, then you know all the more significant bits have been set. If not, then not all of them were set.

Comment: Nope. Disproved with this simple case: ~(0xffffffff >> 1) is 0x80000000, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to compiler right now, so excuse compilation errors,
but here is the solution I'd use in general lines:

step 1: prepare the desired mask. This is done as static variables array, to improve performance (function won't need to allocate the array on stack at each call).

note: every entry at mask relates to the relevant n mask you need. so that
mask[3] means the bits fron n and on set.

```
static masks[17] = { 0b0000000000000000, //this entry is not in use
                     0b1111111111111111, //or use 0xFFFF
                     0b1111111111111110  //or use 0xFFFD
                     0b1111111111111100, //or use 0xFFFB
                     0b1111111111111000, //or use 0xFFF8
                     ...
                     }
```

now you can access directly the number you want

```
if ( ( bit_rank & mask[n] ) == mask(n) )
    printf( "all bits fron n and on, are set\n" );
```